# How to get this message to stop showing?

Tags: debugging, pycharm, message

How can I get this dialogue box to stop showing every time I use the "RUN" shortcut. It doesn't show when I click on the RUN button.

[image]

I research but couldn't get anything online.

Is there something in the menu I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong action, try the shortcut associated with "Run | Run" (⌃+R on macOS)

[image]